# add some delays between request in promis.map using cheerio and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, bluebird, cheerio

I have following code:

`urls` have `5000` different url, when I try to grab and scrape these `urls`, I ran into a `500` Error, so I decide to add some delay between each request, I add the `{concurrency: 1}` but nothing changed.

```
const requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

for (var i=1; i<=250; i++)
{

p="https://mywebsite.com/" + i.toString() 

 urls[i-1]= p 

   
}

Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
  .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {


    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);

    $('.txtSearch1').each(function () { 
        var h="";
        h=$(this).text()
        h= h.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")

        html44.push (h)


})
    shareTuple[urls[index]] = html44;
    html44=[]


   fs.writeFileSync( "data.json", JSON.stringify(  shareTuple ) )
    
     
  }, {concurrency: 1})
  
  .then ()
  .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
```

> how I can add some random delay between each request here? I should using my code, so I need a solution or modification on my code.

Update:

I learn from answers, but just one point is remain in this question. How I can detect which URL cause to 500 Errors and skip it? How I can find about URL ran into 500 Error?

Comment: 500 error is not necessary means you need to limit your request. [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means that. So maybe investigate why you are getting 500 at the first place?

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of the code? Also, you are using `Bluebird` right?

Comment: What is `Promise.map`? Is not standard JS, is it?

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut As we don't know what API is being called, it may just be badly implemented and not be able to deal with to many requests in a proper way and just throw exceptions ...

Comment: @derpirscher Right. Also, @moji-moji, it seems you are not awaiting actions inside the promise at all... so basically you are firing all of them, one-by-one, but while not awaiting for completion it is the same as without `concurrecy` property at all.

Comment: Not sure, whether this is only here in the question or also in your code, but you are not passing the options `{ concurrency: 1}` as parameter to `Promise.map`, because the paramterlist for `Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)` ends right after `requestPromise` ... Instead you are passing it as second parameter (which is probably ignored) to `.map((htmlOnePage, index) =>{...}, { concurrency: 1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a bit of a problem with which parameters you are passing to what function. Currently you do as follows

```
Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
  .map((htmlOnePage, index) => { ...}, { concurrency: 1})
  .then(...)
```

which has multiple issues, so I'm quite wondering how that would even run without throwing Syntax errors ...

1. you are not passing your options `{ concurrency: 1}` to `Promise.map` but to the latter `Array.map` (where they are ignored)
2. `Promise.map` does return a Promise, which does not have a `.map()`
3. `Array.map` does not return a promise, so you can't call `then()` on it ...
4. You are (synchronously) writing into the very same `data.json` file for each of the returned values. You probably want to go through the results first and then just write the file once everything is finished.

The proper code would be something like this

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs"; //provides promise based fs operations

Promise.map(urls, requestPromise, { concurrency: 1})
  .then(values => {
    values.map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
      ...
      html44.push (h)
    })
    let sharetuple = html44;
    return fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(sharetuple));
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
```

I don't know, whether `cheerio` is something async as well. I suppose not. If yes you have to handle that accordingly ...

**EDIT**

If you still think, you need a delay you can add it as follows (but I think, you should address the issue on the backend, if you have access to it)

```
function delayedRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 100))
    .then(() => requestPromise(url));
}
```

and then call

```
Promise.map(urls, delayedRequest, { concurrency: 1})
  .then(values => {
    values.map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
      ...
      html44.push (h)
    })
    let sharetuple = html44;
    return fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(sharetuple));
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
```

But you could also ditch Bluebird completely and do it with the built-in `async await` of JS

```
async function scraper(urls) {
  for (let u of urls) {
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 100));
    let res = await requestPromise(url);
    ...
    html44.push(h)
  }
  await fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(html44));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your second `.map` call does is to wait until all requests are resolved, which is sent parallel, and then do another round of mapping with your html processing.callback

Although I think derpirscher's suggestion should work, I give mine here

```js
Promise.map(
  urls,
  (url, index) => {
    return requestPromise(url).then((htmlOnePage) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
      const html44 = [];
      $(".txtSearch1").each(function () {
        var h = "";
        h = $(this).text();
        h = h.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        html44.push(h);
      });
      shareTuple = html44;
      fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(shareTuple));
      // delay 5s
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5e3));
    });
  },
  {
    concurrency: 1,
  }
).catch((e) => console.log("We encountered an error" + e));
```

Comment: updated in my answer

Comment: Disclaimer: my code is to demonstrate the right direction, not to provide a working version that you can directly use. The `index` you want should be obtained from the `.map` callback

Comment: so very good. I got it. one remain problem. how I can say that if Error 500 is reached for one url go to next url address? bypass 500 and fetch next url? this completely solved my problem.

Comment: just catch the possible rejection of requestPromise and swallow it. `requestPromise(...).then(...).catch(e=> do_wharever_you_want_just_not_to_throw_error)`